# python: py2exe paramiko showing no results

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, paramiko

I am using python 2.7.11 on Windows 7 64bit, I am facing a problem with py2exe when I import paramiko module, the .exe file runs but does not show any results, after executing it closes immediately knowing that i did not get any error during the conversion.

```
import paramiko  
print raw_input("press enter to exit")
```

the setup.txt file:

```
from distutils.core import setup  
import py2exe  
setup(console=['test.py'])
```

I have found that in the "dist" folder there are some dll files such as API-MS-Win-Core-ErrorHandling-L1-1-0.dll - API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll - API-MS-Win-Core-LocalRegistry-L1-1-0.dll, such files I don't usually face them on another machine, so could anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after importing some modules:

```
import appdirs               
import packaging             
import packaging.version     
import packaging.specifiers  
import packaging.requirements
```

hopefully that could be useful for someone.